# Can I use Xamarin to develop client app for MongooseIM server.

Tags: xamarin, mongoose-im

Can I use Xamarin to develop client app for MongooseIM server. Is there a Xamarin Library for MongooseIM and if not can we use the native libraries available from MongooseIM for Android and IOS to develop Xamarin client app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a native library in Xamarin by creating a binding library for it in [Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/) and [iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/), respectively.